# Check if map contains point as key

Tags: java, hashmap, point

I'm working with a school project and got one tiny little thing left before I can hand in in 30 mins!

I have a map, where I can put places on! These places have x and y coords. I can hide these places and then I have a button and after that I can click my map if there is any place hiding there. The thing is I can't get it to work.

I have a hashmap that takes my position class as a key and the place as a value.

I get my x and y from where I click and I wanna check if my position map contains that.. Here is my code so far

```
class WihMouseLis extends MouseAdapter{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mev){
        int x = mev.getX();
        int y = mev.getY();



        if(posMap.containsKey(new Position(x,y))){
            System.out.println("TEST! did i hit it?");
        }


    }
}
```

is there any other way or am I doing it wrong! I have done my own equals and hashCode method in my position class!

my position class

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class Position extends JComponent {
  private int x,y;

  public Position(int x, int y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;   
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

  public int HashCode(){
    return x*1000+y;    
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(other instanceof Position){
        Position p = (Position)other;
        return p.x==x && p.y==y;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Position class.

Comment: There is most likely something wrong with the code in your Position class

Comment: `hashCode` is lower case, by the way.  You officially don't have it overridden.

Comment: `HashCode` has the wrong name. It should be `hashCode`. This is what the `@Override` annotation was created for.

Comment: You spelled hashCode wrong.

Comment: That shouldn't matter because the default hashcode should work so I doubt that's related to the problem.

Comment: changed to hashCode, still nothing :/

Comment: How is your map created? Did you by any chance initialize it with a Comparator? Can you show that code.

Comment: @BenjyKessler my "map" is just a picture. in a JPanel, or my own modified JPanel

Comment: The `MouseEvent` refers to a coordinate grid of one pixel wide cells. Do your positions really refer to cells of one-pixel? Shouldn't you make some computation to convert from pixels to positions instead?

Comment: We need a complete example that we can run, otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: @pbabcdefp well, it's alot of code and different classes that I shall post then :/

Comment: No don't post them all. Narrow it down to the smallest example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What is the key value in your map? HashMap is <K,V> and I assume you have <K,Position> but you use containsKey(new Position(...)) to look for the object?

Comment: @mrak <Position, Place> position is the key

Comment: Have you checked, that your `MouseAdapter` is registered somewhere and has ever been called?

Comment: @tomse yepp, I print out x and y in terminal just to see if it works

Comment: I assume you print out all the keys of your map as well to see if one position would fit?

Comment: @tomse Hm, tried that now.. and the coords in my map are really off somehow,,